# AEM: 'No Design' message displays in the error logs

Tags: adobe, aem

Does anyone know what's the problem?

```
714 GET /data/www/aem6-dispatcher/cache/content/sites/my_project/404.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.designer.DesignerImpl No design at /etc/designs/my_project. Using default.
272 GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.designer.DesignerImpl No design at /etc/designs/my_project. Using default.
168 Cannot find Microsoft Cloud Config at /etc/cloudservices/msft-translation/system_default
46 GET /resources/images/img2.jpg HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.designer.DesignerImpl No design at /etc/designs/my_project. Using default.
40 GET /resources/images/img3.jpg HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.designer.DesignerImpl No design at /etc/designs/my_project. Using default.
```

.....

And many other similar logs. But favicon and other image is shown

.content.xml from /etc/designs/my_project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:Folder">
    <clientlib/>
    <jcr:content
        cq:doctype="html_5"
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        jcr:title="My Design"
        sling:resourceType="wcm/core/components/designer"/>
    <favicon.ico/>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: Is the node at `/etc/designs/my_project` definitely an instance of Cq:Designer?

Comment: @anotherdave please could you clarify? I have little experience in this environment

Comment: Maria, the error you are getting is assuming that a new design has been defined called *my_project* under http://localhost:4502/miscadmin#/etc/designs As Sandeep mentions below, the design is what ties the CSS & JS to a particular site, alongside what components are available for authors

Comment: @anotherdave it strange for me because css and js from /etc/designs/my_project - works.

Comment: Hi Maria, yes, you would still be able to load files from under that path manually, even if the node itself isn't a "Designer" resourceType, but it may affect the ability to, e.g. allow/restrict placing components on certain regions of a page

Comment: @anotherdave "error you are getting is assuming that a new design has been defined called my_project"   - that is to say - I just not correctly identify it in localhost:4502/miscadmin#/etc/designs - this problem in .content.xml ?

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you could post up some code that's causing the issue —e.g. the XML for the design & the page that's referencing it causing the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107224/discussion-between-maria-and-anotherdave).

Comment: @anotherdave i added content for xml, any page calls this error. Sorry for many guestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every project has [design](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/the-basics/designer.html) associated with content. It contains CSS, JS, images etc which are used in components, templates. Also when you edit the page in [design mode](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/page-authoring/default-components/designmode.html) to choose allowed components, that information is also stored under design.

It seems the project you have created is not having design associated and hence the warning, project using default path for storing design information.

You can refer [official docs](https://docs.adobe.com/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can not find information about the activation - activation of design is a prerequisite here http://localhost:4502/miscadmin#/etc/designs ?

Comment: @Maria, you have design, you also need to associate that design to your page. The page of website needs to provide cq:designPath property. Have you associated the design with your page? From the links I shared in response "Designs are stored under /etc/designs. The path to the design to be used for a website is specified using the cq:designPath property of the jcr:content node"